# How to get user input as a matrix format to perform matrix addition in php? anybody having suggestions?

Tags: php, input, matrix, addition

How to get user input as a matrix format to perform matrix addition in php?  anybody having suggestions?

Comment: Give an example of expected result and show what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a option to user with two input box . 
First for rows and second for columns;
Generate a table based on these input through javascript having textbox in each  and 
input box name should be in array based on rows and columns while you are generating.
let says, user enters :- 
rows : 3
columns: 3

> > generate table throrugh javascript
> >     your table should be

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[0][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[0][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[0][]" value=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[1][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[1][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[1][]" value=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[2][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[2][]" value=""/> </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="matrix[2][]" value=""/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and get a two dimension arrray when form is posted .

```
<?php
$matrixArr = $_POST['matrix']; // it will be a two dimenssion array having value as  matrix have
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...  I can create a dynamic table using for loop. so it is very use full. in this place you named the text box as "matrix[][]" it is possible to use <?php $matrix[$i][$j] ?> like this here?

Comment: a 2D array always represent a matrix.so name should form in the manner  that can represent a matrix. now with your code <?php echo $matrix[$i][j]?> will print value of this array position so it will not be array. you can write this <?php echo 'matrix['.$i.']['.$j.']';?> so it will print matrix[1][2], that will be needed.

Comment: can we directly assign a array from form or only we should use form method?

Comment: here i am using 2 loops. if i use name for text box as <?php $matrix[$i][$j]; ?> what will happen?

Comment: As you can see , you are not printing , so variable will not print value but as server send response to browser , it does not send variable , it can only send variable value ,while it was echoed . so in your script you will get blank name like name="" in your html page.

Comment: Thank you so much to clear my queries... I have another query. please clear it. <?php echo 'matrix['.$i.']['.$j.']'; ?> here what is the purpose to use .(dot)? is not necessary to use $ prefix to matrix?

Comment: Actually , i am making a string  when it will be printed , it would be matrix[1][2], in you html page. where matrix ,[,] are static but values are changing. so $i and $j are variable having dynamic value and while  printing making a string , form like matrix[1][2]. that is an array for html page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34897/discussion-between-cj-ramki-and-developerck)

Comment: How to assign this java script variable in for loop to get continues values?

Comment: which javascript variable?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and possibly most intuitive) way would be to present the user with a `<textarea>` and ask them to input the matrix values in the following format:

```
a b
c d
```

Values in individual rows are delimited by spaces, and rows are delimited by newlines. Here's a quick and easy way to generate a matrix out of the submitted `<textarea>`:

```
<?php

  $txt = $_POST['matrix'];

  $mat = explode ("\n", $txt);

  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof ($mat); ++$i)
    $mat[$i] = explode (' ', $mat[$i]);

?>
```

Of course, the same code would work for values delimited by comma, or any other delimiter you see fit.

A less intuitive way would be to present the user with a literal matrix of `<input>` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do, using input fields.

```
<?php
function show_matrix($num, $cols, $rows){
for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<$cols; $j++){
        echo '<input size=2 name="matr['.$num.']['.$i.']['.$j.']"/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
}
show_matrix(0, 3, 3);
echo '<br/>';
show_matrix(1, 3, 3);
?>
```

first matrix: `$_POST['matr'][0]`, second: `$_POST['matr'][1]`